# Get option values from drop down box with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Just start learning CasperJS, I know I can use the following to obtain the texts of the options:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.example.com/test.aspx', function() {
  this.evaluate(function () {
    this.echo("Values: " + this.fetchText('#mySelect'));
  });
});
casper.run(function () {
    this.exit();
});
```

where `mySelect` is a `<select>` in the page. Sample HTML is as follow:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

My aim is to get the values (1, 2 and 3) from the `mySelect`. How can I do this in CasperJS? I tried the following code, but nothing shows up:

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    var options = document.getElementById("mySelect").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        this.echo('Options: ' + options[i]);
    }
});
```

After a bit debugging, `options` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is basically the same as PhantomJS' [`page.evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) (I linked both so you can read both carefully). It is the sandboxed page context. Variables from the outside are not available in there and `this` refers to `window`. I doubt the page has the global functions `echo` and `fetchText`.

Note that DOM elements cannot be passed from the page context. You will have to build a representation like:

```
var options = this.evaluate(function() {
    var options = document.getElementById("mySelect").children;
    return [].map.call(options, function(opt){
        return {val: opt.value, text: opt.textContent};
    });
});
```

or simply

```
var options = this.getElementsInfo('#mySelect > option');
```